# .gitignore what is the difference between subdir/* and subdir/?

Tags: git

```
test/test/build64/ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

The file above is ignored using following pattern:

```
build64/
```

But, the pattern below doesn't work.

```
build64/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference is that `build64` does not have a slash in it.

I know you actually wrote `build64/` and `build64/*`, and `build64/` *does* have a slash in it, but `build64` *does not* have a slash in it and that's what makes all the difference.

Have a look at [the gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and scan down to the section headed with **PATTERN FORMAT**.  Note the bullet point that begins with:

> - If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description ...

The rest of the text is, I think, very confusing—*too* confusing—but the key here is that `build64/` has its ending slash removed first, so that it doesn't have a slash in it any more.  So *now*, if Git encounters a file named `test/test/build64/ALL_BUILD.vcxproj`, Git breaks that name into four *file name components*, which are:

- `test` (the first `test` in `test/test`);
- `test` (the second `test` in `test/test`);
- `build64`; and
- `ALL_BUILD.vcxproj`.

Does **any one** of these four components match `build64`?  Why yes, the third component *does* match `build64`.  The original `build64` had a suffix slash, so is that component a *directory* name rather than a file name?  Yes, it is: so `test/test/build64/ALL_BUILD.vcxproj` is ignored by the rule `build64/`, which does not contain a slash except for that ending slash that does not count.

On the other hand, if you write `build64/*`, Git *does not* remove the slash, so the pattern includes a slash.  Git breaks down the full name `test/test/build64/ALL_BUILD.vcxproj` exactly as before, but this time, it requires that *all* those name components match the *complete pattern*.  Do **all four** of the name components match `build64/*`?  Well, `build64/*` starts with `build64`, and the first name component is `test`.  This **does not match** so the match as a whole immediately fails.

Note that if you were to write `test/test/build64/*` as your `.gitignore` line, Git would match `test/test/build64/ALL_BUILD.vcxproj` against `test/test/build64/*`.  Now the first component `test` must match `test`—it does—and the second component must also match `test`, which of course it does as well.  The third component must match `build64` and the last component, `ALL_BUILD.vcxproj`, must match `*`.  All of these requirements are met, so this *would* select the file to make Git shut up about untracked-ness.

You could also write `**/build64/*`, because `**` matches *any number of* leading components.  This would match the full name `test/test/build64/ALL_BUILD.vcxproj`, but also `build64/file`, `fred/build64/wilma`, and `fred/wilma/build64/betty`.  Note that it would *not* match `fred/wilma/build64/barney/betty` because `barney/betty` has too many components—but if you match the directory `fred/wilma/build64/barney`, Git may never bother to look *inside* `fred/wilma/build64/barney/` to find `betty` anyway.

In any case, it's important to remember that shell-style matching is done *one file name component at a time*, except for the `**` matches.  The "all must match" rule is triggered by a gitignore pattern that includes an embedded slash; otherwise only one component must match.  Trailing slashes are, as the documentation almost says,

> removed for the purpose of

deciding whether to use the "all must match" or "only one must match" rule.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much for  the "all must match" rule and remove slash rule. I never heard of it before.